# E/PhoneWindows: "Horizontal progress bar not located in current window decor"

Tags: android, android-layout

My app used to display a progress bar at the top, from Android 2.2 to 4.3 (API 8-18), but now when adapting it to Android 8-13 (API 26-33), I no longer see it.

Instead, I am getting this error message in the Debug log:

> E/PhoneWindow: Horizontal progress bar not located in current window
> decor

Googling this error message, only yields [PhoneWindow.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/880eff6/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/PhoneWindow.java) source code, logging it 6 times as in:

```
    final int features = getLocalFeatures();
    if (value == PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON) {
        if ((features & (1 << FEATURE_PROGRESS)) != 0) {
            if (horizontalProgressBar != null) {
                int level = horizontalProgressBar.getProgress();
                int visibility = (horizontalProgressBar.isIndeterminate() || level < 10000) ?
                        View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE;
                horizontalProgressBar.setVisibility(visibility);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Horizontal progress bar not located in current window decor");
            }
        }
```

Well, I do have in my app's activity's onCreate() the following line:

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
```

But according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window, the  PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON constant was deprecated in API 24, FEATURE_PROGRESS and related methods are no longer supported starting in API 21.

How do I bring back my progress bar?

**Update:**

I originally had the following main layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/title_bar"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/composite_layout"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_without_this_nothing_works"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
      <ViewFlipper
          android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <com.example.olib.OWebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.example.olib.OImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/exampleGray"
            android:contentDescription="@string/lo_imageview_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/static" />
      </ViewFlipper>
    </RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I then added ProgressBar right above ViewFlipper:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/viewflipper"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="1"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

and in the activity I set the ProgressBar's visibility to View.VISIBLE, but for some reason I don't see it.

Comment: You should use `ProgressBar` on the UI as `Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS` is deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change your code as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/title_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/composite_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_without_this_nothing_works"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="1"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
            
            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_below="@id/progress_bar">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/black"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
            </ViewFlipper>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I get below output

[image]

I think progressbar overlapped by another view do changes same as my code and I hope it will work for you

> android:layout_alignParentTop="true"-> add this line in progressbar
> android:layout_below="@id/progress_bar"-> add in ViewFlipper same as code.

Comment: It looks like the `android:layout_above="@+id/viewflipper"` line was the culprit. I now see a progress bar while loading a page on the WebView. It doesn't look like the one in your screenshot (thin green line) but at least I got something to start working with. Thank you.

Comment: I am happy It help you. That green line I just add to see in preview and yes output will be defiantly different bcz. I take normal webview and Image view and don't load any data so its black.